# app reload of iOS React Native project (in simulator) started fading out green loading bar really slowly

Tags: ios, react-native

For some reason I can't pinpoint, my React Native project on iOS started reloading extremely slowly. Basically the initial screen and green fade out over like 8 seconds. So it makes app reloads a lot slower.

Has anyone experienced this? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Xcode simulator go to **Debug** > **Slow Animations** or **cmd+t**